# What is the oauth_token in signed_request used for in the Facebook App flow?

Tags: facebook, authentication

Is it possible to request the access_token using the oauth_token and, say, the app_secret, somehow?

(If not, what on Earth is the oauth_token for?)

Or do I need to make an oath-request each time a user (new session) visits my page to obtain a code for access_token retrieval?

(If yes, how do I enable a smooth user experience for returning users? I do not want to send them back and forth through jscript redirect, yet at the same time I would like to stay in the FB iframe)

Best regards,

SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your page is loaded in FB IFrame, Facebook will pass you a valid signed_request in a POST variable.  You normally wouldn't need to get one if your page is loaded as a FB Canvas application.

You don't really need to use OAuth Token anymore.  What you want to use are:

1) User signed_request, passed into FB IFrame
2) App access token, for pulling application insights or accessing request 2.0 objects.

**Here's how you process the signed_request ([official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)):**

If the validation doesn't work out, you can send them to this URL to have them go through the facebook authentication then return to your page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<URLENCODED_APP_URL>
```

For more detailed information, such as how to get user access token for a brand new user that just authorized your application and how to get app access token, you can refer to the official documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Hmm, but... do I need to make a request, each time a user comes back ("per session") to the access token request page, as per the doc page you referenced, like this: 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
Or can I, by means of the oauth_code, get the access_token without getting a redirect... sort of. Ah, I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: I mixed up some language earlier - I should say that facebook will pass you a "signed_request", which is all you need to validate an user.  I have updated the original answer to include the correct information and links to examples.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a clearer picture of this now! Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `oauth_token` is sort of your "public key" that was used to make your access token and sign your request. Your access token is encoded in that `signed_request` variable you get from the `POST`. If you're using the Facebook PHP SDK, it automatically parses this for you (and I imagine other official SDKs behave the same way), and you can simply call `$facebook->getAccessToken()` if you need it.

- If you need it, [more information about decoding the signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)